# Alsa works in virtual console but not in X Windows

Tags: xorg, alsa, virtual-console

After booting my computer and logging in on a virtual console the aplay command works as expected but after running startx only root can run aplay. As non-root I get the following error message:

```
$ aplay foo.wav 
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1401:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
aplay: main:682: audio open error: No such device
```

Any clues?

Comment: What are the permissions in `/dev/snd/` after running `startx`?

Comment: CL: Owner `root` and group `audio` have read and write access both in the console and in X

Answer (score 1):

After adding myself to the *audio* group I can use Alsa in X Windows:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G audio august
```

The question remains though, how come I'm able to use Alsa in a virtual console without being root or in the audio group?